# How do I get the count of loans? Why isn't this working?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working with playground, similar to SQLite

There are two tables: `loans_west` and `loans_east`

Both have columns for: `id`, `book_id`, `patron_id`, `loaned_on`, `return_by` and `returned_on`

The query I'm trying is to generate a report that lists a patron's first name, email and loan count for loans that haven't been returned.

So far I have

```
SELECT first_name, email, Count(1) as [Count]
From
(
SELECT book_id FROM loans_west bn WHERE return_by IS NULL
union all
SELECT book_id FROM loans_east bs WHERE return_by IS NULL
)
GROUP BY patron_id
```

None of this is working though. 
How do I do this? Thank you

Comment: Where `Title` coming from ?

Comment: Well, what does the error message say?

Comment: Error: no such column: first_name

Comment: Well, you only have those `id, book_id, patron_id, loaned_on, return_by and returned_on` in your hand

Comment: The reason for that is that you're not selecting from a table on that level, you're selecting from a subselect, and the result of that subselect does not contain first_name, it only contains book_id.

Comment: You should consider not having two tables for loans as well, and instead make the "east" and "west" distinction a column in the one loans table.

Comment: I'm not able to change how the tables are displayed unfortunately. I'm just working through some exercises in a playground. I can't get my head around this one though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner query must contain all the columns that you are referencing in your outer query otherwise it will throw error column not found.

```
SELECT patron_id, email, Count(1) as [Count]
From
(
SELECT patron_id, email FROM loans_west bn WHERE return_by IS NULL
union all
SELECT patron_id, email FROM loans_east bs WHERE return_by IS NULL
)
GROUP BY patron_id,email
```

As mentioned in your question the column list of tables doesnot have first_name as column. Assuming that there is a mapping table for patron_id and first_name, the table containing further details of of person
you can use JOIN to get first name.